# Is there a way to pack a python project with all dependencies but not as an executable, but with access to the code?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, pyinstaller, python-venv

since I think the original post wasn't clear enough -

***EDIT:***

Is there a tool or an option to pack my python project and all of it's dependencies and sub dependencies - same as `pyinstaller` does, but `pyinstaller` generates an executable binary, and I'd like to have the ability to make changes in the code after it's distributed (e.g on a client's environment)

***Original Post***

I have this python project, with a lot of dependencies and sub-dependencies, that's currently distributed by building it using `pipenv` to create a virtual environment and getting the 3rd party libraries, and `pyinstaller` to generate an executable which is being used on a virtual machine with another OS (I'm packing an executable to the target's machine OS by building it on a docker with the same OS).

the thing is - I'm using some data and scripts from this virtual machine in my python project, so i can't run it locally, and whenever there's a bug, or an error, I have to make changes locally and rebuild (which takes some time) and only then move the executable to the vm in order to run it.

my goal is to have all of the code packed with the dependencies, but with the structure of my project, and not as executable, so I can make quick changes on the VM itself.
The VM may not have an external connection, so I can't just install the dependencies on the machine.

is there a tool that can help me do such a thing?

*Note*

Currently the python version on the VM is different than the python version the project uses. it's possible to install another version if necessary.

Comment: Look into Docker.

Comment: @preritdas I'm using docker in order to pack the project to the same OS as the VM, but I don't see how to use it to pack it differently.
can you elaborate?

Comment: You can at least do a multi-arch build on docker using a single manifest. For doing multi-OS you have to have different image or a layer at least

Comment: @Daniel The key is your `Dockerfile`. The way you structure your Dockerfile determines how your container is formatted. For example, if you're building a Python program on a Windows machine and packaging it for an Ubuntu server, you would write your file with `RUN python -m venv venv && source venv/bin/activate` as opposed to `RUN python -m venv venv && venv/Scripts/activate`. I'm not a Docker expert at all, but this tends to work for me.